# entity framework dotconnect for oracle command timeout

Tags: oracle, entity-framework, dotconnect

The default command timeout property in connection string is not working. I am trying with Entity Framework and have a default command timeout=60 in the connection string. It is not throwing an error after 60 sec. Is this a bug?

Answer (score 1):

The Default Command Timeout connection string parameter of the myOracleConnection object determines a default value of the CommandTimeout property of all OracleCommand objects created basing on myOracleConnection.

The value of the CommandTimeout property is used in the [**Direct Mode**](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle/docs/?directmode.html) only. The OCI mode (via Oracle client) doesn't take into account cmd.CommandTimeout, and the duration of command timeout is determined by Oracle client settings. Are you connecting in the [**Direct Mode**](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle/docs/?directmode.html)?

Be aware that OracleCommand.CommandTimeout property determines the time to wait for the server response (it can be "error" or "success, wait for result set"). So OracleCommand.CommandTimeout does not control the time of fetching the data.